# Can someone explain this code to me intuitively (finding nCr without overflow error)?

Tags: java, math, factorial

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-calculate-the-value-of-ncr-efficiently/

this is the code I want to understand. Here is a video that explains it more in-depth https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhXwT7Zm3EU -> however, I still don't understand a certain aspect of it.
Here is the code:

```
// Java implementation to find nCr
 
class GFG {
 
    // Function to find the nCr
    static void printNcR(int n, int r)
    {
 
        // p holds the value of n*(n-1)*(n-2)...,
        // k holds the value of r*(r-1)...
        long p = 1, k = 1;
 
        // C(n, r) == C(n, n-r),
        // choosing the smaller value
        if (n - r < r) {
            r = n - r;
        }
 
        if (r != 0) {
            while (r > 0) {
                p *= n;
                k *= r;
 
                // gcd of p, k
                long m = __gcd(p, k);
 
                // dividing by gcd, to simplify
                // product division by their gcd 
                // saves from the overflow
                p /= m;
                k /= m;
 
                n--;
                r--;
            }
 
            // k should be simplified to 1
            // as C(n, r) is a natural number
            // (denominator should be 1 ) .
        }
        else {
            p = 1;
        }
 
        // if our approach is correct p = ans and k =1
        System.out.println(p);
    }
 
    static long __gcd(long n1, long n2)
    {
        long gcd = 1;
 
        for (int i = 1; i <= n1 && i <= n2; ++i) {
            // Checks if i is factor of both integers
            if (n1 % i == 0 && n2 % i == 0) {
                gcd = i;
            }
        }
        return gcd;
    }
 
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 50, r = 25;
 
        printNcR(n, r);
    }
}
```

Specifically, why does this code work:

```
if (n - r < r)
  r = n - r;
```

Why, by doing this simple operation, produce the right answer eventually after going through and exiting the main while loop? I don't understand why this is necessary or why it makes sense to do. Like, why would not having this code make the nCr calculation fail or not work the way it's intended???? If someone can either explain this or point me to somewhere that does explain it or the math concept or something that would be great :) Maybe another way of coding the same thing would help. I just want to understand why this produces the right answer as a math and coding student.
To give a bit of perspective on my abilities (so you know what level I'm at), I am learning object-oriented programming, and have completed high school maths and basic computer science. I am by no means an expert.

Comment: Compared to what?  Surely the more important question is ... why does some other method of calculation get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nCr` operation has a speciality and it is mentioned in the comment above the `if` condition : `// C(n, r) == C(n, n-r)`. Now, the while loop iterates when `r>0` and with each iteration the value of r is decremented by `1`. So in order to reduce the number of times the loop is executed, we need to reduce the value of r (if possible). Since `C(n, r) == C(n, n-r)`, we take the smaller value among `r` and `n-r` so that the number of iterations are minimized but the result remains the same.

Assume that `n = 100` and `r=99`. In this case if we skip the `if` condition, then the loop would be executed `99` times, whereas using the `if` condition we could update `r` as `r = n-r` so that `r=1`, then the loop would have been executed only once. Thus we are saving `98` unwanted iterations.

So there is a big performance improvement if we include the `if` condition.